# Parsing phpdoc comments using PHPDocumentor

Tags: php, phpdoc

I'm looking to convert PHPDocumentor output to a format I can traverse through in PHP (Ideally, I want an array of all the functions with their comments).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pure php reflection to get the phpdoc content. We used that to put there input validation data. I'll look up example code later.

Just use this:

```
$data = new ReflectionMethod($class, $method);
echo $data->getDocComment();
```

Answer (score 2):

Zend_Reflection might be of some use: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.reflection.reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the `parse` option of [DocBlox](http://docblox-project.org) to generate a XML structure which you can then interpret with your own code.

After you have installed DocBlox using [PEAR](http://pear.docblox-project.org) you can use the following command to generate a structure.

```
docblox parse -d [SOURCE_FOLDER] -t [TARGET_LOCATION]
```

or

```
docblox parse -f [SOURCE_FILE] -t [TARGET_LOCATION]
```